# Why Viewpager instantiateItem() load two times in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
I am creating Viewpager dynamically which it is according to the size of the List

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.domore.viewpagerposition.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager_recent_matches"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager pager;
    List<String> lst=null;
    LiveAdapter adapter=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager_recent_matches);
        lst=new ArrayList<>();

        lst.add("notstarted");
        lst.add("started");
        lst.add("started");
        lst.add("notstarted");

        adapter=new LiveAdapter(this,lst);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here is my Adapter class

```
public class LiveAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> lst;
    String lst_value="";

    public LiveAdapter(Context context,List<String> lst){
        this.context=context;
        this.lst=lst;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lst.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==((LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        final View itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_layout,container,false);
        TextView txtname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);

        itemView.setTag(position);
        lst_value=this.lst.get(position);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos=(int)itemView.getTag();

                if(pos==0){
                    if(lst_value.equals("notstarted")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "notstarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if(lst_value.equals("started")){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

it print started on the toast message this is the problem.

I got value i log when i run an application.

```
01-18 16:53:15.769 27799-27799/com.domore.viewpagerposition E/POSITION: 0
01-18 16:53:15.769 27799-27799/com.domore.viewpagerposition E/POSITION: 1
```

After load an application i tried to swipe and position return directly 2.

My question is why i was got two time position value at a same time????
When i swipe then why i was got 2 instead of 1????

Please, help me to solve out this problem

Comment: Try this code and please give a valid answer.

Comment: after launching what was the text displayed on the view

Comment: add your activity_main.xml also

Comment: actually i was not set any data on the view but if i set the position on the textview then i got four viewpager and i got the perfect position like 0 on first, 1 on second, 2 on third and 3 on fourth Viewpager.

Comment: Is your problem only the log? Do the contents get displayed properly?

Comment: No dude log is not a problem. Imaging  on 0 position of the List<String> i got the value like "notstarted" and on 1 positon of the List<String> i got the value like "started". I got both of the value in to single variable namely status.It's load two time so the status variable value is "started" instead of "notstarted" because it's load two times. This is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer of @Daniel Zolnai he was absolutely right.
Here, i found a perfect solution of the post.

Pass another List from your homefragment to adapter like below:

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

//Now, add the elements to the newly created list

list.add("notstarted");
list.add("started");
list.add("started");
list.add("notstarted");

//Add into adapter constructor parameter
adapter=new LiveAdapter(this,lst,list);
```

Here, is your constructor of adapter

```
public LiveAdapter(Context context,List<JSONObject> lst,int pagerLength,List<String> list_status){
        this.context=context;
        this.lst=lst;
        this.list_status=list_status;
        this.pagerLength=pagerLength;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Here, is your adapter code onclick() method

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String status_value=list_status.get(position);
                if(status_value.equals("notstarted")){
                    Log.e("status",""+status_value);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,NotStartedMatchDetails.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

don't forget to make your position parameter as **final** of instantiateItem() method paramter.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the ViewPager is preloading pages for smoother animations.
The default pages to load outside the current one is set to 1.
That means that on startup it loads the default one (0) and the one next to it (1). When you swipe to the first page, it has to preload the one next to it, with the position 2.

You can increase this value using `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(number);`

The minimum value is 1, which is also the default value.

If you just want to get the current position, use a listener on your ViewPager:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
   // Called when the scroll state changes (scroll started - ended)
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, 
    float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
   // This is called a lot of times when the user is scrolling
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
      // Check position here to see which page was selected
  }
});
```

Comment: How can i avoid this problem?

Comment: This is not a problem, this is how viewpager works. Just try it out.

Comment: You don't understand how the viewpager works. You should not check for the position there, but with an OnPageChangeListener, as I said.

Comment: I understood but according to your last comment.if i click on viewpager then where i need to put my code??

Comment: You can just make the position parameter final and then check that position.

Comment: You should write your code in fragments better when using viewpager.